Using a Dynamic Range as the Data Source for a Pivot Table
I currently have a datasource with 1 row of data that is just headers. The data gets inputted dynamically through a upload process. Im trying to create a pivot table using my data's dynamic range.
I use this Formula below for the pivot table which allows me to get the range of data for my table without including any blanks. The issue is when I try to apply the formula for the pivot table it states that I need two rows as a source. However, right now I wont have more than 1 row until my data gets added. Is there any way around this?
=OFFSET(Data!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Data!$A:$A),51)

=OFFSET(Data!$A$1,0,0,MAX(2,COUNTA(Data!$A:$A)),51) ?
